# Tools to generating a grammar using examples?

Tags: grammar, text-mining

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245485/algorithms-or-patterns-for-reading-text/1247649#1247649) shows a pretty example of using a parser generator to look through text for some patterns of interest.  In that example, it's product prices.

Does anyone know of tools to generate the grammars given training examples (document + info I want from it)?  I found a couple papers, but no tools.  I looked through [ANTLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) docs a bit, but it deals with grammars; a "recognizer" takes as input a grammar, not training examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a machine learning problem.  You can at best get an approximation.  But I don't think anybody has done this well, let alone released a tool.  (I actively track what people do to build grammars for computer languages, and this idea has been proposed many times, but I have yet to see a useful implementation).

The problem is that for any fixed set of examples, there's a huge number of possible grammars.  It is easy to construct a naive one:  for the fixed set of examples, simply propose a grammar that has one rule to recognize each example.  That works, but is hardly helpful.  Now the question is, how many ways can you generalize this, and which one is the best?  In fact you can't know, because your next new example may be a total surprise in terms of structure.  (Theory definition: A language is the set of sentences that comprise it).

We haven't even talked about the  simpler problem of learning the *lexemes* of the language.  How would you propose to learn what legal strings for floating point numbers are?

Comment: Well explained.  So it is still research.  How would I propose learning legal strings for floating point numbers?  How about gathering up all my examples then asking me for a little bit of grammar for what "4.3" "2.2" and "1.0" share?  Or trying to detect well-known primitives?  That is just off the top of my head, but I can see it would be hard.

Comment: @drfankow: how is that different than the original question you asked?  If you want to see how hard this is, go examine all the variations of string literals you can write in Python 2. (Then look at Python 3, where they changed them somewhat).  Are there people building machine learning algorithms to do this kind of thing? Yes. None useful in my field; frankly, it is easier to write down a guessed description myself.

Comment: @drfrankow: one of the tenets of machine learning is, "you can't learn it unless you almost already know it". For the simple example of floating point numbers, you want the concepts of "digit", "natural", "fraction", "exponent", "sign", and "other". If you have these concepts, you have a much better chance of learning "sequence(fraction,optional(exponent))". Without these, your learner might take the examples you provided and "learn" the regular expression "([124]\.[023])", which even generalizes from the cases given. You can't object that is wrong, it covers all the cases. But is it helpful?

Answer (score 2):

One tool that does this is [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/). I Highly recommend it, and [the O'Reilly book that covers it](http://www.nltk.org/book/) is available free online. There are tools for parsing, learning grammars, etc... The only downside is that it is mainly a research rather than production tool, so the emphasis isn't on performance.

NLTK is able to construct grammar from labeled training samples, which is *exactly* what you are asking. Have a look at the great docs and the book. (My last experience with it also had it working on the JVM through Jython without any issues.)

Comment: The problem isn't that you can't induce some kind of grammar to cover the instances you see.  It is getting a grammar that covers what the language will *accept*.   Without that, you get a parser that at best *mostly* works.   Users hate flaky tools.  Those get rejected really fast.

Comment: @IraBaxter Agreed. This is not a problem that any tool can solve with 100% accuracy. Natural languages are ambiguous anyway (time flies like an arrow, fruit flies like a banana). That said, NLTK will do _exactly_ what is asked by the OP, with a plug-and-play model for different algorithms to solve this problem. I'm willing to bet I could get a 98% rate on parsing numbers with a good labeled training corpus, with maybe a dozen lines of python. With a little more effort, that languages of "Numbers" could be parsed with near perfect accuracy without ever having to write a parser yourself.

Comment: I agree, NLTK will probably induce *some* grammar just like OP asked,   My point is that 98% on parsing computer langauges is a disaster.  And OP is asking this, hoping he can avoid writing a real grammar because that's hard to do.  This is a fairy tale.

Comment: Whether a given accuracy is good enough depends on the use case. There are plenty of cases where 98% accuracy is more than good enough. I've personally worked on several, notably parsing free-text engineering reports. NLTK was a great tool then and served us very well for the exact use case the OP is describing. When there is an actual formal grammar, write a parser. The real world isn't always that clean though, and extracting semantics from free text _can't_ be done with a formal grammar, because there isn't one.