# Parsing incoming email content from a range of set templates

Tags: php, regex, parsing, email

Working on a project that requires incoming email to be parsed, and certain information be extracted and stored in the database. We're using postmarkapp to extract the body content of the email so we only have the text only guts of it, but I'm currently a bit stuck on how to parse the email the most efficient way.

Over time we'll be adding more 'accepted' formats of incoming mail, but to start off with we'll have probably 4 common emails coming in, that is, they'll follow the same format and the information that we want to extract (contact details, id's, links, bio)  will be in the same place, (per supported format).

I'm thinking that we'll have an interface that will handle the common tasks, and each supported format will implement that, however just how to get that information is where I'm stuck.

Open to any thoughts and ideas on different methods / technologies to do this, ideally PHP, but if we need to use something else, that's fine.

Comment: The mail you are trying to parse are coming from a single form on a website or something, or from any email client ?

Comment: They will be coming from a few select third party sites, so the format will be the same, however we don't have control over the actual content if that's where you were heading

Comment: Could you atleast post the format you are getting the mails in and what you want out of them? That way we can help you construct a regular expression and perhaps even come up with better solutions...

Comment: unfortunately I can't, it breaks an NDA, but more importantly, I'm not after a specific solution but instead a technique / direction as we'll need to write quote a few of these over time

Comment: @duellsy well, it's hard to help you in this case. Most cases can surely be solved with [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). They are often the way to go for this kind of parsing. They break down once you start to have nested structures, but it sounds like you just want a few bits of (flat-hierarchy-) information just end up in different places of the email. Couldn't you at least give an example that doesn't give away your specific format or data but still captures the overall structure of it?

Comment: thanks @m.buettner for the input. Unfortunately not, it will become obvious extremely fast if I provide anything but the most basic example, which is easy to parse

Comment: Is this about detecting a specific format or extracting data from a given format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar feature on a site that I developed. Our users get emails from their suppliers with pricing. They copy and paste the body of the email into a textarea on our site and click a button. Then we parse the text to find products and prices and stick the info into a database.

To do the parsing, we first have to determine the supplier, like you'll need to do to determine which template was used. We look for certain strings in the text - the supplier's name usually, or a line that's unique to their emails. We do that in a method called something like `getParserForText()`. That method returns a Parser object which implements a simple interface with a `parseText()` method.

There's a Parser implementation class for each format. The `parseText()` method in each class is responsible for getting the data out of the text. We looked for ways of making these elegant and generic and have simply not found a really good way to do that. We're using a combination of regular expressions, splitting the string into smaller sections, and walking through the string.

Pseudocode:

```
$text = $_POST['emailBody'];
$parser = getParserForText($text);
$result = $parser->parseText($text);
if(count($result["errors"]) > 0)
{
    // handle errors
}
else
{
    saveToDatabase($result["prices"]);
}
```

We have no control over the formats the suppliers use, so we have to resort to things like:

1. split the text into an array of strings around each line with a date (prey_split())
2. for each element in that array, the first line contains the date, the next three to six lines contain products and prices
3. pull the date out and then split the string on new lines
4. for each line, use a regex to find the price ($000.0000) and pull it out
5. trim the rest of the line to use as the product name

We use a lot of `prey_split()`, `preg_match_all()` and `explode()`. While it doesn't seem to me to be particularly elegant or generic, the system has been very robust. By leaving a little wiggle room in the regular expressions, we've made it through a number of small format changes without needing to change the code. By "wiggle room" I mean things like: Don't search for a space, search for any whitespace. Don't search for a dollar sign and two numbers, search for a dollar sign and any number of numbers. Little things like that.

EDIT:

Here's a question I asked about it a few years ago:
[Algorithms or Patterns for reading text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245485/algorithms-or-patterns-for-reading-text)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This is just what I was looking for. Pseudo code and general flow. Champ. I award thee, the bounty

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's generated email, It most likely comes in an easily parsable format, such as one line per instruction; `key=value`. You can then split the lines on the first `=`-sign and use the key-value pairs that this gives you.

Regular expressions are great for when you don't have control over the incoming data format, but when you do, it's easier to make sure it is parsable without a regexp.

If the format is too complex for such simple parsing, please give an example of a file using the format, so I can make the answer more specific. Same thing if this isn't an answer to what you mean to ask: please give an example of the sort of answer you want.

Comment: it definitely isn't key value as neatly as we'd like it to be, unfortunately I can't show an example email content as we're under NDA, I'm at this stage just really after techniques / direction (as opposed to a specific solution for a given format, as we've got a lot to write up), I'll take your suggestion as regular expressions

Comment: Yes. If it's not immediately clear how to do it without regexps, then they are probably the easiest way. With them, it should be quite easy to get any data you want out of the message.

Comment: Why don't you at least give us a glimpse of how the format looks like? You can alter names and replace actual data with trash values